# I have JASONArray for facebook images how to load pic in imageview - Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

Here is the FB Graph url - https://graph.facebook.com/198403540272980/photos/?fields=name,source&limit=0

```
            String jsonUser = fb.request("198403540272980/photos/?fields=name,source&limit=0");
            obj = Util.parseJson(jsonUser);


            JSONArray dataArr = obj.getJSONArray("data");  



            for(int i = 0; i< dataArr.length()-1; i++)
            {
                **Need code to load image to imageview**
            }
```

Any help???

Answer (score 0):

first you need the photoURLs

```
for (int i=0; i<dataArr.size(0; i++){
    picUrl = dataArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("source");


}
```

To put it in an imageview, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Comment: Actually I need clarity on how to display images whether to download them first in SD card and then show them or directly.